# How to Assign a Value 1-10 Over Thousands of Entries??

Tags: algorithms, education

First, I am not a mathematician. So, have patience with me please. I want to be able to assign a number (1-10) to n-amount of people, based on a given action. If that person does less of that action, they receive 1. If they do more (or the most), they receive a 10. And everything in-between for less extremes.

An example of this would be scoring people who watch tv. Someone who watches 40 hrs of tv per week should receive a 10 compared to everyone else who is only watching 20 hrs or 10 hrs.

What is a formula for this? I am trying to score people based on their actions COMPARED to other people doing that same action. Thanks for your time.

Comment: How do you _measure_ the action?

Comment: In the example for tv watching, the action is number of hours watched. If you mean literally how I am measuring this, I am using technology. An app, for example, that records session time.

Comment: Let's say $x$ represents your _measurement_ of the action, $y$ the threshold for that action, and $S$ the score that they receive. Then for a person $p_i\in P$, where $P$ is the set of all people, and $i = 1, 2, \cdots,\vert P\vert$, $$S(p_i, x_i) = \begin{cases}1 & \text{if } x_i\le y \\ 10 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$

Comment: @an4s Can you provide an example of this formula in use? I do not understand. And I am not certain this would work. I guess since we are talking about time, there is a threshold of the action. Particularly hours in a week. But what if I am measuring number of button clicks? Now threshold is infinite. Is there an universal answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want [feature scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling).

Min-max normalization (described in the article above) gives you scores between 0 and 1, which you can multiply by 10 if you want. One thing that might be undesirable about this approach is that if one person watches a million hours of TV, everyone else's scores will be low. An alternative approach that guarantees that the scores are evenly distributed is to arrange the people in increasing order of your metric and assign a score based on where they fall in the sorted list. This amounts to computing [percentiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile).

Comment: The percentiles sounds like what I want. Reading the wiki, this is it! Can you help me understand the formula though. Hard for me to grasp. Also, do you agree that percentiles is the way to go?

Comment: It really depends on how you intend to use these scores, but yeah, percentiles are informative. To compute them, just sort the list of people in order of how much TV they watch and use each person's index in the sorted list (divided by the total number of people, and multiplied by 10 if you want) as their score. For example, the 2500'th person in a list of 10000 people would get a score of 2.5 out of 10.